# Javascript disable submit button unless if all html validations are fufilled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form:

```html
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Name</span> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="Estate name..." id="Editname" required />
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>Address</span> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="Address..." id="Editaddress" required />
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>Upload</span> 
      <input type="file" placeholder="Upload File..." id="Editupload" required />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <span>@@</span> 
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="Editemail" required />
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>Tel</span> 
      <input type="tel" pattern="^\d{4}\d{3}\d{4}$" id="Editnumber" required placeholder="Phone no..." />
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>@@</span> 
      <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" id="EditfileUpload" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Each of these fields has required and some sort of validation.

I want to disable the "Submit" button when the user enters for example the email in the right format, the correct length of the phone number etc.

How can I do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery validate would be my first choice.  If you don't want a 3rd party library, then override the submit button's action.

```
document.getElementById('EditfileUpload').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do your validation checks here.

    document.forms['myform'].submit();

});
```